# BizTalk connectivity issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am facing a connectivity issue in BizTalk 2010, We are connecting third party service which expects authentication header for security connection. for this we have written custom authentication header logic and given reference to the BizTalk in send port in behavior section and passed the credential using basic http adapter. In recent days we are facing below connectivity issue. However after restarting the host instances connection is establishing. we are facing this issue frequently.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Can you show some code examples to illustrate your question please ?

Comment: Please add the error text as well.

Comment: Also can you explain what you are connecting to?   Sometimes things change at the end you are connecting to.

Comment: There are several kinds of authentication. What kind do they expect? How you implement that depends on the kind of send port are you using

Comment: Are you using oAuth?  If so what is the logic to expire the token and get a new one?

Comment: thanks for response, Can you please share your email so that  I can share the code

Comment: Can you please send a text mail to my email ID "sdn.biztalk@gmail.com".

Comment: client web service expects Authorization Header to be passed in every request sent from external systems. To send this Http Header from BizTalk to call the service, we have implemented a custom behaviour component which adds the Http Authorization header whenever BizTalk calls any operation of client web service. we had faced this connectivity issue four times in last six months, after restarting the host instances connection is establishing.

Comment: please find the below error desc:     The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "WcfSendPort_dest" with URL "https://xyz". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was ''. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: Could you please respond on this